# Как зациклить исполнение скрипта на selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Всем привет! Нужна помощь сообщества. Никак не могу зациклить исполнение скрипта на `selenium`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://nsagov.ru/Users/Login.aspx")
print("[+] Открыли страницу авторизации")
time.sleep(5)

forgot_pass_xpath = '/html/body/form/div[4]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/div/a/span'
browser.find_element_by_xpath(forgot_pass_xpath).click()
print("[+] Нажали кнопку Забыли пароль?")
time.sleep(5)

email_xpatch = "/html/body/form/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/input"
browser.find_element_by_xpath(email_xpatch).send_keys("test@test.ru")
print("[+] Ввели электронную почту")
time.sleep(5)

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_GetNewPasswordPopup_TPCFm1_GetPasswordButton_CD']/span").click()
print("[+] Отправили запрос на смену пароля")
time.sleep(5)

close_xpath = '//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_GetNewPasswordPopup_HCB-1"]/img'
browser.find_element_by_xpath(close_xpath).click()
print("[+] Закрыли окно")
time.sleep(5)

browser.quit()
print("[+] Выход из программы")
```

Comment: Как сделать с помощью selenium - не знаю, но вам в помощь обычный цикл `while True:`

Comment: @DeNRuDi пришлось повозиться, но я справился с помощью `while  True:`. Напиши ответ, я приму.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы зациклить программу - самым простым способом будет создать бесконечный цикл `while True`.

Есть еще один вариант с циклом `for`, но элегантнее выглядит именно с `while`.

Небольшой пример:

```
from time import sleep

while True:
    sleep(5)  # задержка на 5 секунд
    # ваш код и дальнейшее выполнение программы
    break  # остановка цикла
```